# main.jsbundle.map could not be found. Ensure the --sourcemap-output option is passed to the react-native bundle command

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, macos

I tried to archive my react native project using **Product** > **Archive** on XCode14.2. But I'm getting this error:

```
    export WRAPPER_SUFFIX\=.app
    export WRAP_ASSET_PACKS_IN_SEPARATE_DIRECTORIES\=NO
    export XCODE_APP_SUPPORT_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode
    export XCODE_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION\=14C18
    export XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL\=1420
    export XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR\=1400
    export XCODE_VERSION_MINOR\=1420
    export XPCSERVICES_FOLDER_PATH\=PickupAppV2.app/XPCServices
    export YACC\=yacc
    export _WRAPPER_CONTENTS_DIR_SHALLOW_BUNDLE_NO\=/Contents
    export _WRAPPER_PARENT_PATH_SHALLOW_BUNDLE_NO\=/..
    export _WRAPPER_RESOURCES_DIR_SHALLOW_BUNDLE_NO\=/Resources
    export __IS_NOT_MACOS\=YES
    export __IS_NOT_MACOS_macosx\=NO
    export __IS_NOT_SIMULATOR\=YES
    export __IS_NOT_SIMULATOR_simulator\=NO
    export arch\=undefined_arch
    export variant\=normal
    /bin/sh -c /Users/jamesku/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PickupAppV2-bdtpzdicjgbodpdojnmikcdhwrmk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PickupAppV2-DEV/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/PickupAppV2.build/Release-iphoneos/PickupAppV2.build/Script-023B83D0DA214377BFA53CD9.sh

Error: SOURCE_MAP /var/folders/bx/fdwrm4kd7fn6h7kylslgj1340000gn/T//4e26d60a5d37aa8a4edb6ec522927ef6-main.jsbundle.map could not be found.
Ensure the --sourcemap-output option is passed to the react-native bundle command.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

screenshot:

[image]

I've tried to enable source maps following the official documentation, but this didn't solve the problem:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/sourcemaps#enable-source-maps-on-ios
[image]

Also tried to generate the map manually by running `NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider react-native bundle --entry-file='index.ios.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --sourcemap-output ios/main.jsbundle.map`

And add main.jsbundle.map to

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I met same error today, and I solved it by deleting `ios/build` folder.